# External library (Box2D) missing declarations after building

Tags: box2d, unresolved-external, external-dependencies

I am trying to incorporate the Box2D physics library into my project. I built it and did all the other steps necessary to use it in my project - this works fine and I can access all it's members by doing `#include <Box2D.h>`. However when I try to build my solution, I get the error ***"unresolved external symbol 'public: _thiscall...'"*** indicating that the functions I am trying to call are not declared. When checking the include directory of the Box2D library, my CPP files are all there. When checking the External Dependancies folder however, they are not (I'm not sure if this is relevant but I thought it was worth mentioning). I would highly appreciate if someone could help me out of this dilemma! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show the full sentence of compile error.  It will help identifying the class that is missing.   Did you try to build your project before incorporating Box2D?

Comment: I fixed it - the problem was I was building it with the wrong SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I was building the library with the wrong SDK, hence why it was not compatible with my project.